# Regex Screaming Frog - Find in Body Text a kwd that is not link

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I need a regex for `ScreamingFrog` that will extract, only from the body text, a `kwd` that is not anchor of a link.

I got this one right now that brings back all ocurrences outside and in the body text, I need another version of the regex that will output only body text non links kwds.

```
(?!<a[^>]*?>)(keyword here)(?![^<]*?<\/a>)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It is easier for others to help you with your regex question if you provide sample input and expected output :) Please edit your question with these and you will get help faster.